# How to make background fill the entire div using CSS

Tags: html, css

how could i expand background image in full height?
http://codepen.io/aalis/pen/egmmeW

```
.navbar-default { font-family: 'Montserrat', serif; background: #ccddff; border-bottom-color: #DFDFDF; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 0; }
.navbar-header .navbar-brand {
  font-size: 36px; color: #b37700;
}
/*--HOME--*/
#home {
  background: url('http://s17.postimg.org/m4bfqfgn3/fog_1005445_1920.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Comment: is [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKPQWd) what you are trying to achieve? or [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygNveg) ?

Comment: this is it !!! thanx man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKPQWd)

You will have to use the `background-size` property in CSS.

To make the image completley cover your div you can use

```
 background-size:100% 100%;
```

Please read more about it in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Answer (score 0):

If you want full height you can use below in your css:

```
img { height:100% }
```

and if you want full screen image you can use:

```
img { height:100%; width:auto; }
```

Comment: The OP has no `<img>`..He is using `background` in his CSS. I recommend you to read the question carefully before answering.

Comment: yeah. my fault. sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
background: url("your image url") no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-size: cover;  
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
```